# What happens in spark when we write into a dynamically partitioned hive table?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Say, we have a dynamically partitioned hive table and we want to write to it in Spark. What is the optimal way of doing so?

Say, the table is partitioned on the `date` column. Will spark first `repartition` (not `partitionBy`!) the `Dataframe` by this column and then write into hive partitions? Or does it not do this? If it doesn't, should I do this (`repartition` by date before writing into this table)? Will it increase performance?

Are there any in depth tutorials about this out there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same partitions then give will create new partitions for new data.

For example, if table is partitioned by `order date`, and you have data till 31-may-2023. While inserting data for 1-jun-2023, hive will create a new partition for 1-jun-2023 and keep all associated data in it.

Repartition in spark is applied to dataframes. You can save it as a table but you can't repartition an existing hi e table. Spark df repartition is not related to hive table repartition.